# Write in .plist file iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, plist

```
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Ramesh</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>Delhi</string>
    </dict>
```

How do I  write this  in my plist file and at run time within any specific parent tag.

Comment: Do you have an plist or you write to NSUSerDefaults?

Answer (score 0):

Just setting up this dictionary, this is how to write the plist to the apps directory.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name", @"Ramesh", @"Address", @"Delhi", nil];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary.plist"];
[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This code is working but it is not able to write data in the dictionary.plist file. Can you help me why it is not adding the data in the .plist file? Thanks.

Comment: It worked fine for me.  Wrote the document in the iPhone Simulator's document directory just fine.

Comment: It might also be an issue that you are trying to write data that isn't able to be put into a plist.  Plists are limited to strings, numbers, arrays and dictionaries.